# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout Logcat error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerview for a chat application so i need to implement the users so i got them from the firebase and everything was working once i added their images , the images doesn't show up in the recyclerview and it gets me error "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

this is the function i use for implementation and i call it in the onCreate method

```
  fun fetchUsers(){
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
        ref.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("NewMessageActivity",it.toString())
                    val user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
                        adapter.add(UserItem(user!!))
                    adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->
                        val intent = Intent(view.context, ChatLogActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }
                }
                recyclerViewNewMessages.adapter=adapter
            }

        })
    }
```

and this is the class i call

```
class UserItem(val user : User): Item<ViewHolder>(){
    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.user_row_newmessages
    }

    override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        viewHolder.itemView.tv_UserNamenewed.text = user.userName
        Picasso.get().load(user.profileImage).into(viewHolder.itemView.iv_UserPhotonewed)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign and empty adapter at start, then add the data to your adapter when you have it. This way you will not see this log.

In other words, if you do assignment in the main thread, for example in `onCreate()` of the activity, you will not see this. However, the first place you set the adapter is in a asynchronous code block. Everything is already drawn and the recyclerview hasn't provided an adapter yet, so it prints this log.